# In C++, make an alias const

Tags: c++, alias

I'm a beginner to C++ and I have a question that I want to make sure...I've done pretty of searching online.

Let say I have a class call A and it has a function called Afunction. The function looks like:

```
// this is pseudocode
void Afunction (const A& a)
{
 a.something = a.something +1;
}
```

My understanding is we have an "pointer-like" thing called 'a' and it's an alias to whatever we pass in. Here we only make sure the alias itself is const, but no guarantee that the value to which it points at won't be changed. In fact, I'm changing it..and I don't get no error.

So my question is, how can I make sure the values that the alias is point to can't be changed? It's much easier to be done if it's pointer other than alias...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code shouldn't compile.

Comment: The code *can* actually compile, if `A::something` is of a type that has the assignment operator overloaded, and declared as `const`. (unless I missed something)

Comment: It can also compile if A::something is mutable.

Comment: `// this is pseudocode`... well, show `// real code`

Comment: @Zyx2000 Heh, just because it can doesn't mean it should!

Answer (score 2):

If a compiler accepts that code, you should ditch it immediately.

You can't modify `a`.

Answer (score 2):

`A const&` (which is unforunately equivalent to `const A&`) is a *reference to a `const` object*.

Similarly, `A const*` is a *pointer to a `const` object*, whilst `A * const` is a *`const` pointer to an object* and `A const * const` is a *`const` pointer to a `const` object`.

The key is to read (and write) your type declarations from right-to-left.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what is `something`.

If you posted the code of class A, it would be easier to explain why you can change `something`.

In general, you can't modify contents of `const A&`. But...

- `something` can be static, then const doesn't matter since `something` doesn't technically belong to the `a` variable in `Afunction`.
- `something` can be declared `mutable`. Sometimes having a member variable that can be changed even when the object is const is beneficial. For example, reference counting.
- `something` may be something completely different, with weird semantics. (as Zyx 2000 pointed out).

Comment: It is unusual to have public mutable data.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not a syntax error. [Check it yourself](http://ideone.com/b6f5sa).

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I agree that would be rare. But it is possible.

Comment: +1 You are completely right. I should have coffee before typing anything.